# Refresh power query VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

So I use the below code to refresh my Query connections, however, how can I display a message if my refresh failed due to wtv reason? as this VBA shows me refresh complete even though there are multiple errors with my queries.

```
'Worksheets("Details").Unprotect
 Dim Connection As WorkbookConnection
    Dim bugfix As Integer
    
        For bugfix = 1 To 2

            On Error Resume Next
            
            For Each Connection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            
                With Connection
                
                    If (.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC) Then
                        .ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
                    
                    Else
                    
                        If (.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB) Then
                            .OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
                    
                        End If
                    
                    End If
                
                End With
            
            Connection.Refresh
            
            Next Connection
            
        Next bugfix
'Worksheets("Details").Protect , AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True
MsgBox "Refresh Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh power query using VBA (1004 Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74670417/refresh-power-query-using-vba-1004-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belive it will stop at `Connection.Refresh` - with the Debugger. And if you want to catch this Error in your Sub you need to define something like `On Error Goto MyError` and then handle the Error with a message or something. `Resume Next` will then continue your code on the next line of your error.

```
Exit Sub
MyError:
MsgBox (Err.Description)
resume next
End Sub
```

Described here at: [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement)

Comment: Thank you, kind sir, it worked! I've been searching for days now!